# SQL Help - Insert into a table, data from two different tables, based on a reference table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a four tables I am working with.  One of the tables is empyt (ATM) with three columns (ID, Cust_AcctID, Brch_CtyID)  and I would like to insert data into the Cust_AcctID and Brch_CtyID columns of this table.

**ID   |  Cust_AcctID  |  Brch_CtyID**

The second table (Cust_Acct) also has three columns (ID, Customer and Account)
The Customer and Account columns hold string data.  The ID value in this column is what I am looking to have inserted into the ATM table in the Cust_AcctID column

**ID   |   Customer    |    Account**

1 |  John Doe     |   Checking

2   |  John Doe     |   Saving

3   |  Jane Doe     |   Checking

4   |  Jane Doe     |   Plan24

The Third table (Brch_Cty) has three columns as well (ID, Branch and City)
The Branch and City columns hold string data. The ID value in this column is what I am looking to have inserted into the ATM table in the Brch_CtyID column.

**ID   |     Branch      |    City**

1   |  Main Branch    |   New York

2   |  Second Branch  |   New York

3   |  Main Branch    |   Chicago

4   |  Uptown Branch  |   Detroit

The fourth table is a reference table that holds all the valid combinations Of (Customers, Account) and (Branch, City).  All data in these columns are strings.

**Customer    |    Account   |     Branch      |    City**

John Doe      |  Checking    |  Main Branch    | New York

John Doe      |  Savings     |  Second Branch  | New York

John Doe      |  Checking    |  Uptown Branch  | Detroit

Jane Doe      |  Checking    |  Uptown Branch  | Detroit

Using the data from table 4, I would like to insert into the ATM table the the data from the ID column from the Cust_Acct Table into the Cust_AcctID column where it matches the data in the fourth table.  The same goes for the Brch_Cty table ID to be inserted into the Brch_CtyID column

So the ATM table should look like this

**ID   |  Cust_AcctID  |  Brch_CtyID**

1|1|1

2|2|2

3|1|4

4|3|4

Could you please help me with building a SQL statement for this.  I am really stuck figuring this one out.  Thanks for any help given.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: First try writing a select query by performing the joins on these tables..

Comment: something like.. 'Select CA.ID,BC.ID from Cust_Acct Inner join Reference_table R ON CA.Customer = R.CUSTOMER and CA.Account = R.Account

and further

Comment: Yes, I tried the following without the insert into.  Select(ca.id, bc.id) From dbo.temp t Inner join dbo.Cust_Acct ca on ca.Customer=t.Customer AND ca.Account=t.Account inner join dbo.brch_cty bc on bc.Branch=t.Branch AND bc.City=t.City Where ca.Customer=t.Customer AND ca.Account=t.Account AND bc.Branch=t.Branch AND bc.City=t.City

Comment: Did that work ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following :

```
Select ca.ID,bc.ID
From dbo.temp t Inner join dbo.Cust_Acct ca on ca.Customer=t.Customer AND 
ca.Account=t.Account 
inner join dbo.Brch_City bc on bc.Branch=t.Branch AND bc.City=t.City 
Where ca.Customer=t.Customer AND ca.Account=t.Account AND bc.Branch=t.Branch 
AND bc.City=t.City
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks Ram, that query is the same as the query I put in my comment above. it does not return the value I am expecting.

Comment: @RobKinnaird - There's a slight difference.
What you have mentioned is "Select(ca.id, bc.id)" while I have mentioned "Select ca.ID,bc.ID"

Can you make these changes and try ?